# what does flush function do in python i have some examples but all the outputs are the same with or without this function?

Tags: python

```
fileObject = open("functions.txt", "w+")
fileObject.write("test")
fileObject.close()
fileObject.flush()
fileObject = open("functions.txt", "r")
fileContent = fileObject.read()
print("\nBefore flush():\n", fileContent)
fileContent = fileObject.read()
print("\nAfter flush():\n", fileContent)
fileObject.close()
```

results:

```
Before flush():
 test

After flush():
```

the code after removing `flush()`:

```
fileObject = open("functions.txt", "w+")
fileObject.write("test")
fileObject.close()
fileObject = open("functions.txt", "r")
fileContent = fileObject.read()
print("\nBefore flush():\n", fileContent)
fileContent = fileObject.read()
print("\nAfter flush():\n", fileContent)
fileObject.close()
```

results:

```
Before flush():
 test

After flush():
```

what does flush() do in python ????

Comment: It doesn't do *anything* useful after closing the file, as closing a file automatically flushes it. Your code also doesn't test anything useful. Why do you  think the flush would cause any change to `fileContent` between those two calls to `print`?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-flush-method-in-python/

Comment: i found this function when i was searching the web and i was curious about it i know the buffer is a reserved area of memory that has been created by the os itself for temporary storage